# How to add new dict to list of dict with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Let's say this is a sample json.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "details": [
    {
      "a": "100",
    }
  ]
}
```

The result that i want is add `{'b': '200'}` to details and it will look like this.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "details": [
    {
      "a": "100",
    },
    {
      "b": "200",
    },
  ]
}
```

In my file, I have tried many times but it still doesn't work So, how to add dict with sqlalchemy

```
class Models(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    details = Column(JSONB, nullable=False, server_default='[]')


@router.post("/post2")
async def post2(id: int = 1):
    session = Session()
    user = session.query(Models).filter(
        Models.id == id).first()
    for var in user.details:
        var.append({"b": "200"})
    session.commit()
    return user
```

Comment: You need mutation tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536752/2681632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `flag_modified`, becuase you cannot update JSONB directly:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified

@router.post("/post2")
async def post2(id: int = 1):
    session = Session()
    user = session.query(Models).filter(
        Models.id == id
    ).first()
    
    user.details.append({"b": "200"})
    flag_modified(user, "details")    
    session.commit()
    return user
```

or rewrite whole collection:

```py
import copy

@router.post("/post2")
async def post2(id: int = 1):
    session = Session()
    user = session.query(Models).filter(
        Models.id == id
    ).first()
    
    details = copy.deepcopy(user.details)
    details.append({"b": "200"})
    user.details = details   
    session.commit()
    return user
```

Here is similar topic: [Updates to JSON field don't persist to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559434/updates-to-json-field-dont-persist-to-db)

Comment: Thanks, Based on your advice, which one should I use flag_modified or copy.deepcopy?

Comment: If you modify a huge part of your dict I would rewrite structure using deepcopy. But when you add only one key, flag_modified looks more appropriate.